# Edit csv with php

Tags: php, csv

I have csv with about 700 rows. It includes rows like:

```
92265R-1,1
92526R-3,0
.
.
.
```

Now my goal is to copy every row to new csv where every row is copied with _x end for 5 times. So final csv would look like this:

```
92265R-1_1,1
92265R-1_2,1
92265R-1_3,1
92265R-1_4,1
92265R-1_5,1
92526R-3_1,0
92526R-3_2,0
92526R-3_3,0
92526R-3_4,0
92526R-3_5,0
.
.
.
```

I'm stuck here

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this

```
$newArray = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

  for($i=1 ; $i <=5 ; $i++){
    $newArray[] = [
            $row[0].'_'.$i,
            $row[1]
        ];
   }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

foreach ($newArray as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```